# Can't open my hosted website using FTP from a second computer ( both using Visual Studio 2017)

Tags: visual-studio, ftp

I use Visual Studio 2017 on my desktop which is where I've been developing a new (hosted) website.  I also have a laptop with Visual Studio 2017 that I'd like to use to work on my project while traveling.  I have tried logging in using the same FTP settings as the desktop, but when I enter my username and password it gives me the error message "You are not authorized to perform the current operation."  Am I doing something wrong or is it not possible to log into my website from another instance of VS?

Any insight into why I'm not able to log in to my website would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Message itself saying due to some security you are not getting through, try communicating your host (where your application is deployed), and asked them your FTP client request is getting blocked or not getting through, they will help you with console (I guess)

Comment: Thank you for the quick response.  I am currently pursuing that path.  I've been holding to speak to someone by phone for some time now so I decided to put this question to the community to see if anyone else has encountered this problem.